# How to obtain damping ratio with Curve Fitting Toolbox

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have some experimental data from an oscillating system (time domaine) and I would like to get an approximation of the damping ratio (zeta). I have already try to use the half-power band width method with the vibrationdata Matlab package. But I would like to compare the result with another method.

I found several methods in this paper : [www.vce.at/sites/default/files/uploads/downloads/2007_damping_estimation.pdf](http://www.vce.at/sites/default/files/uploads/downloads/2007_damping_estimation.pdf) and I would like to try to do the curve fitting method with the Curve Fitting Toolbox of Matlab (R2014b) (chapter 2.2.2 Curve fitting in the paper).

It's the first time I use this Toolbox with a custom equation, so, I do not really know how to do it with my sample data.

I do not know how to write in the Curve Fitting Toolbow, the equation of the paper as it involves differentiate equation...

Can anyone help me regarding this.

Comment: Type `cftool` in the matlab window, that will bring up a GUI for you, which is quite straightforward to use. Input your x/y variables, and select a custom model function, then define what you want to fit.

Comment: Hi Andras, thanks for your prompt answer. Actually this is what I try to do. But I am struggling with the wrtitting of the equation define in the paper u(t)=exp(-zeta*omega_n*t....) in the chapter 2.2.2. I do not  manage to write it properly. I have already open the curve fitting toolbox and import my data.

Comment: I'm not in the mood for looking at a paper for you, but I won't be alone with that:) You can call variables whatever you wish, typically x is the independent variable, and y is the model function in the gui, if I remember correctly. You have to write something like `y=exp(-beta*x)*(A*cos(omega*x)+B*sin(omega*x))`, in which case the GUI should figure it out that your parameters to fit are `beta`,`omega`,`A` and `B`. You'll need to give quite good starting parameters for such a fitting problem, I assume.

Comment: I tried to enter something like this : `y=exp(-zeta*omega*x)*(A*cos(omega*sqrt(1-zeta^2)*x)+(B+zeta*omega*A)/(omega*sqrt(1-zeta^2))*sin(omega*sqrt(1-zeta^2)*x))`. With `A`, `B`, `zeta` and `omega` my parameters. But what I do not know how to do is to specify that `A = y(0)`, `B = y' (0)`... I also know that omega is close to 15, but when I replace omega by 15 in the equation I get an error 'Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients....

Comment: You can't tell `A=y(0); B=y'(0)`: those will be output from the fit. For instance, if you evaluate your model function in `x=0`, you can't get anything other than `A` as result. If `omega` is *close* to 15, leave it as `omega`, and set close bounds on it: `[10, 20]` or even closer. It needs a lot of fiddling to get it right, if you're unsure about the important parameters. It often helps if you increase fitting parameters, such as `MaxFunEvals` and `MaxIter`.

Comment: Thanks. I start to have something that works.

Comment: fit a damped harmonic oscillation? Take a look at this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50756-fit-a-damped-sine-wave and that: http://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/795.php Cheers
Detlef

Comment: Does it hve to be in Matlab or would e.g. Python also be ok? Could you post some data?